# Hibernate transaction and session with multiple save

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, jpa, transactions

Thanks, let me completely change it.

Using:
Spring Boot, Hibernate JPA

I have created a link table with a composite primary key across all 3 columns(event_attendee_link_program)

I used the JPA tools in STS IDE to generate Entities from my tables and it came up with the below code. I removed some of the columns to save space.

**EventAttendee.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="event_attendee")
@NamedQuery(name="EventAttendee.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM EventAttendee e")
public class EventAttendee implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="attendee_id")
private long attendeeId;



//bi-directional many-to-one association to EventAttendeeLinkProgram
@OneToMany(mappedBy="eventAttendee")
private List<EventAttendeeLinkProgram> eventAttendeeLinkPrograms;



public List<EventAttendeeLinkProgram> getEventAttendeeLinkPrograms() {
    return this.eventAttendeeLinkPrograms;
}

public void setEventAttendeeLinkPrograms(List<EventAttendeeLinkProgram> eventAttendeeLinkPrograms) {
    this.eventAttendeeLinkPrograms = eventAttendeeLinkPrograms;
}

public EventAttendeeLinkProgram addEventAttendeeLinkProgram(EventAttendeeLinkProgram eventAttendeeLinkProgram) {
    getEventAttendeeLinkPrograms().add(eventAttendeeLinkProgram);
    eventAttendeeLinkProgram.setEventAttendee(this);

    return eventAttendeeLinkProgram;
}

public EventAttendeeLinkProgram removeEventAttendeeLinkProgram(EventAttendeeLinkProgram eventAttendeeLinkProgram) {
    getEventAttendeeLinkPrograms().remove(eventAttendeeLinkProgram);
    eventAttendeeLinkProgram.setEventAttendee(null);

    return eventAttendeeLinkProgram;
}
}
```

**EventAttendeeLinkProgram.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="event_attendee_link_program")
@NamedQuery(name="EventAttendeeLinkProgram.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM EventAttendeeLinkProgram e")
public class EventAttendeeLinkProgram implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private EventAttendeeLinkProgramPK id;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to EventAttendee
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="attendee_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private EventAttendee eventAttendee;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to EventOptionsAttendeeType
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="attendee_type_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private EventOptionsAttendeeType eventOptionsAttendeeType;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to EventProgram
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="program_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private EventProgram eventProgram;

public EventAttendeeLinkProgram() {
}

public EventAttendeeLinkProgramPK getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(EventAttendeeLinkProgramPK id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public EventAttendee getEventAttendee() {
    return this.eventAttendee;
}

public void setEventAttendee(EventAttendee eventAttendee) {
    this.eventAttendee = eventAttendee;
}

public EventOptionsAttendeeType getEventOptionsAttendeeType() {
    return this.eventOptionsAttendeeType;
}

public void setEventOptionsAttendeeType(EventOptionsAttendeeType eventOptionsAttendeeType) {
    this.eventOptionsAttendeeType = eventOptionsAttendeeType;
}

public EventProgram getEventProgram() {
    return this.eventProgram;
}

public void setEventProgram(EventProgram eventProgram) {
    this.eventProgram = eventProgram;
}

}
```

**EventAttendeeLinkProgramPK.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class EventAttendeeLinkProgramPK implements Serializable {
//default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name="attendee_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private int attendeeId;

@Column(name="attendee_type_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private int attendeeTypeId;

@Column(name="program_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private int programId;

public EventAttendeeLinkProgramPK() {
}
public int getAttendeeId() {
    return this.attendeeId;
}
public void setAttendeeId(int attendeeId) {
    this.attendeeId = attendeeId;
}
public int getAttendeeTypeId() {
    return this.attendeeTypeId;
}
public void setAttendeeTypeId(int attendeeTypeId) {
    this.attendeeTypeId = attendeeTypeId;
}
public int getProgramId() {
    return this.programId;
}
public void setProgramId(int programId) {
    this.programId = programId;
}

public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this == other) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(other instanceof EventAttendeeLinkProgramPK)) {
        return false;
    }
    EventAttendeeLinkProgramPK castOther = (EventAttendeeLinkProgramPK)other;
    return 
        (this.attendeeId == castOther.attendeeId)
        && (this.attendeeTypeId == castOther.attendeeTypeId)
        && (this.programId == castOther.programId);
}

public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int hash = 17;
    hash = hash * prime + this.attendeeId;
    hash = hash * prime + this.attendeeTypeId;
    hash = hash * prime + this.programId;

    return hash;
}
}
```

**EventAttendeeServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
@Primary
public class EventAttendeeServiceImpl implements EventAttendeeService {

@Autowired
private EventAttendeeRepository eventAttendeeRepository;

@Autowired
private EventOptionsAttendeeTypeRepository eventOptionsAttendeeTypeRepository;

@Autowired
private EventProgramRepository eventProgramRepository;

@Override
@Transactional
public String addEventAttendee(EventAttendee eventAttendee) {

        EventAttendeeLinkProgram ep = new EventAttendeeLinkProgram();
        ep.setEventOptionsAttendeeType(eventOptionsAttendeeTypeRepository.findOne(2L));
        ep.setEventProgram(eventProgramRepository.findOne(2L));

        eventAttendee.setEventAttendeeLinkPrograms(new ArrayList<>());
        eventAttendee.getEventAttendeeLinkPrograms().add(ep);

  eventAttendeeRepository.save(eventAttendee);

    return "";
}
```

With this in place, my code is not throwing any errors. It is saving the EventAttendee, but nothing is being saved to the EventAttendeeLinkProgram. Please Note: I am trying so save both EventAttendee and EventAttendeeLinkProgram entities. So I think hibernate should be smart enought to forst save EventAttendee and generating the Id for it, then use that Id to store in EventAttendeeLinkProgram.

Comment: What's the context ? Standalone app ? spring one ? could you show us the sessionFactory creation

Comment: Ok what's your runtime ? tomcat ? java-ee ? standalone ? could you give some exception exemple

Comment: Ok so now i need entites (User and UserType) definition. please add as much information as possible when asking a question, answer depends on the context 99% of the time

Comment: Note that below answer is general advice and won't fix your current problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, user save return the identifier directly

```
Long insertId = (Long) session.save(user);
```

Then you'd better call the rollback on the `tx`transaction itself instead of retrieving again the transaction from the session.

Finally, when using spring you should consider to let spring manage the transaction itself (`container managed transaction)`using `@Transactional` annotation instead of using `user managed transaction`. It's logical as you let spring manage the session for you (`sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`) and both session and transaction should have the same scope (e.g. the unit of work).

Consider reading some literature on `Session` (e.g. JPA `entityManager`) and transaction management.

Comment: Thanks, I completely updated the code and pasted the actual code here.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you let spring do the heavy lifting:

First create a JPA repository in spring:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{
}
```

Then create your 2 entities with the relationship

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<UserType> userTypes;
```

And :

```
@Entity
public class UserType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
```

My test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest extends AbstractTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void test1() throws SQLException {
        showTables();

        User user1 = makeUser("Greg");
        userRepository.save(user1);
        System.out.println(user1);
        userRepository.save(makeUser("George"));
        assertEquals(2, userRepository.count());

        User user = userRepository.findOne(1l);
    }

    User makeUser(String name) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        user.setUserTypes(new ArrayList<>());
        user.getUserTypes().add(makeUserType("admin"));
        user.getUserTypes().add(makeUserType("head chef"));
        return user;
    }

    UserType makeUserType(String description) {
        UserType userType = new UserType();
        userType.setDescription(description);
        return userType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I completely updated the code and pasted the actual code here.